# How to break a for loop from inside an if statement in Julia?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, julia, break

I am trying to translate a python modelisation (not very effective) into a Julia code (more useful in this context) but I didn't find how to break a for loop and how to print a value in this context.

Python code

```
for i in np.range(1, nt)
    if t[x == s] == 100:
        s_time = i*dt
        print(s_time)
        break
```

Julia code I tried :

```
for i = 1:nt
    if round.(Int, t[x.==s]) == 100
        s_time = i*dt
        println(s_time)
        break
    end
end
```

The variables here are not important, but `dt` is a value that allows me to know the time in `[y]` in the for loop in function of `i`, and `t[x.==s] == 100` allows me to know when I want to break the loop.

The Julia code do not returns me any error but do not break and do not print anything.

Full code (for Jupyter Notebook users) :

```
# NUMERICS
ti = 30  # surface temperature
td = 1000  # dyke temperature
tel = 30  # right lim temperature
teg = tel  # left lim temperature
x1 = 80  # central position dyke 2
x2 = 110  # central position dyke 1
d1 = 24  # dyke diameter
d2 = 10  # dyke diameter
s = 160  # probe position

yd1 = 0  # dyke 1 intrusion year
yd2 = 15  # dyke 2 intrusion year

d = 40  # rock diffusivity
size = 200  # size of the model
ttot = 30;  # total time in year

nx = 2001  # cells number
dx = size/(nx-1)  # cells size
dt = dx^2/(2.1*d)  # frame condition
nt = round(Int, ttot/dt)  # frame number
x = LinRange(0, size, nx); # size model

# INITIALISATION
indexing_1_l = round(Int, (x1 - d1/2)*nx/size)
indexing_1_r = round(Int, (x1 + d1/2)*nx/size)
indexing_2_l = round(Int, (x2 - d2/2)*nx/size)
indexing_2_r = round(Int, (x2 + d2/2)*nx/size);

t = ti * ones(nx)
t[indexing_1_l:indexing_1_r] .= td;
using Plots
gr() ;

# PLOTTING LOOP
for i = 1:nt 
    
    q = -d*(diff(t)/dx)
    dcdt = -diff(q)/dx
    t[2:end-1] = t[2:end-1] + dcdt*dt
    
    t[1] = teg
    t[end] = tel
    
    if i == round(Int, yd2/dt)
        t[indexing_2_l:indexing_2_r] .= td
    end
    
    # IF STATEMENT THAT DOESN'T WORK
    if round.(Int, t[x.==s]) == 100
        s_time = i*dt
        println("$s_time")
        break
    end

    if mod(i, 1000) == 0
        IJulia.clear_output(true)
        pt = plot(x, t, label = :false, c="red", title=" $(round.(Int, i*dt)) [y] - Dyke intrusion", 
            xlabel="Distance [m]", ylabel="Temperature [°C]", ylims=(0, 1000), size = (800, 600))
        Plots.display(pt)
    end
    
end
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the Julia code you've posted. Can you share the values of `s`, `x`, `t`, `nt`and `dt` so that your code is a complete [mre]?

Comment: How sure are you your `if` condition is met? *"but do not break or print what I want"* If it doesn't `print` either, it doesn't seem like `break` is your problem. Can you make this example more complete? What is `nt`? What are `t`, and `s`...?

Comment: @geogeo, [edit] your question and add details there instead of in comments

Comment: I added the full code for more precision.

Comment: @geogeo, full code is no good. The M in [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) means _minimal_, and we ask for minimal because (a) nobody wants to read through many lines of irrelevant code and (b) often while condensing down your code to a MRE, you find the answer because you're forced to narrow down the source of the problem.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi You are totally right, narrow down the source of the problem is a good way to find the answer. But in this case, I afraid that my low capacities in coding in Julia do not allow me to do it. Besides, in this specific context, I am not able to write an MRE that highlight my problem either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will never return `true` because an array cannot be equal to a number:

```
if round.(Int, t[x.==s]) == 100
```

Look at this

```
julia> [100] == 100
false
```

It's not completely clear what you want it to mean, but perhaps this

```
if all(round.(Int, t[x.==s]) .== 100)
```

or perhaps `any`?

Comment: `if t[x == s] == 100` doesn't even really make sense in Numpy.

Comment: using `any` is the solution ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

you have a syntax error! println(s_time)

Comment: `println("$s_time")` is not a syntax error, but it unnecessarily creates a string before printing it. You are correct that the OP should use `println(s_time)` instead.